# Selection-sort algorithm sorting wrong

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

Okay I'm having a problem with the selection sort algorithm.  It'll sort ints just fine but when I try to use it for doubles it starts to sort randomly.
here's my code

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Sorter.ListSort;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApp20
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = new List<double>();
            x.Add(23.1);
            x.Add(1.5);
            x.Add(3);
            x.Add(15.23);
            x.Add(101.2);
            x.Add(23.35);
            var sorted = selectionSort(x);

            foreach (double s in sorted)
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static List<double> selectionSort(List<double> data)
        {
            int count = data.Count;
           // Console.WriteLine(count);

            for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
            {
                int min = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
                {


                    if (data[j] < data[min])
                        min = j;

                    double temp = data[min];
                    data[min] = data[i];
                    data[i] = temp;
                }
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is what the algorithm is returning

[image]
As we can see 3 is NOT bigger than 15.23, what's going on?

Comment: I think that you should only be swapping the minimum element in to place after looking through the whole list to find it, not every iteration.

Comment: That got it thanks.  Always great to have an extra set of eyes on it!

Comment: There is no reason that the data type would make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like MoreON already mentioned in the comments, you should swap the elements after you've found the min value.

So it should look like this

```
    public static List<double> selectionSort(List<double> data)
    {
        int count = data.Count;
        // Console.WriteLine(count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
        {
            int min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
            {
                if (data[j] < data[min])
                    min = j;
            }
            double temp = data[min];
            data[min] = data[i];
            data[i] = temp;
        }

        return data;
    }
```

But if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you could also use:

```
var sorted = x.OrderBy(o => o).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change place for **int min**

```
for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
    {
        int min = i;

        if (data[j] < data[min])
            min = j;

        double temp = data[min];
        data[min] = data[i];
        data[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will sort your array but you will have a lot of unnecessary swaps. Selection Sort only swaps (at most) once for each element.

Comment: @SaiBot I agree that my example isn't good, but i did it to it work.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new method called swap and use the following selection sort code.

```
void swap(int *a,int*b){
    int temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}

void selectionSort(int arr[],int n){
int min_index;
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    min_index=i;
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(arr[j]<arr[min_index])
            min_index=j;
    }
    swap(&arr[min_index],&arr[i]);
}
}
```